# C Language: Why int variable can store char?

Tags: c

I am recently reading The C Programming Language by Kernighan.

There is an example which defined a variable as int type but using `getchar()` to store in it.

```
int x;
x = getchar();
```

Why we can store a `char` data as a `int` variable?
The only thing that I can think about is ASCII and UNICODE.
Am I right?

Comment: What is`get char();` Except for a syntax error?

Comment: Characters are represented by numeric codes

Answer (score 6):

The [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function (and similar character input functions) returns an `int` because of `EOF`. There are cases when `(char) EOF != EOF` (like when `char` is an `unsigned` type).

Also, in many places where one use a `char` variable, it will silently be [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` anyway. Ant that includes constant character literals like `'A'`.

Comment: In fact most C library functions that you might assume to take or return a `char` type actually use `int`. The secret is to [RTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) for every function that you use, which was written specifically for you.

Comment: Ah, yes - EOF is generally an int, +1 for your answer instead of mine :)

Comment: This is totally accurate but I don't know if it addresses OP's confusion about types. Many languages do not consider characters to be integers, because of typesafety. (Of course, everything is just a string of bits underneath. But that's not necessarily the point.)

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` attempts to read a byte from the standard input stream. The return value can be any possible value of the type `unsigned char` (from `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`), or the special value `EOF` which is specified to be negative.

On most current systems, `UCHAR_MAX` is `255` as bytes have 8 bits, and `EOF` is defined as `-1`, but the C Standard does not guarantee this: some systems have larger `unsigned char` types (9 bits, 16 bits...) and it is possible, although I have never seen it, that `EOF` be defined as another negative value.

Storing the return value of `getchar()` (or `getc(fp)`) to a `char` would prevent proper detection of end of file.  Consider these cases (on common systems):

- if `char` is an 8-bit signed type, a byte value of `255`, which is the character `ÿ` in the ISO8859-1 character set, has the value `-1` when converted to a `char`. Comparing this `char` to `EOF` will yield a false positive.
- if `char` is unsigned, converting `EOF` to `char` will produce the value `255`, which is different from `EOF`, preventing the detection of end of file.

These are the reasons for storing the return value of `getchar()` into an `int` variable.  This value can later be converted to a `char`, once the test for end of file has failed.

Storing an `int` to a `char` has implementation defined behavior if the `char` type is signed and the value of the `int` is outside the range of the `char` type.  This is a technical problem, which should have mandated the `char` type to be unsigned, but the C Standard allowed for many existing implementations where the `char` type was signed. It would take a vicious implementation to have unexpected behavior for this simple conversion.

The value of the `char` does indeed depend on the execution character set.  Most current systems use ASCII or some extension of ASCII such as ISO8859-x, UTF-8, etc. But the C Standard supports other character sets such as EBCDIC, where the lowercase letters do not form a contiguous range.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar` is an old C standard function and the philosophy back then was closer to how the language gets translated to assembly than type correctness and readability.  Keep in mind that compilers were not optimizing code as much as they are today.  In C, `int` is the default return type (i.e. if you don't have a declaration of a function in C, compilers will assume that it returns `int`), and returning a value is done using a register - therefore returning a `char` instead of an `int` actually generates additional implicit code to mask out the extra bytes of your value. Thus, many old C functions prefer to return `int`.

Answer (score 1):

C requires `int` be at least as many bits as `char`. Therefore, `int` can store the same values as `char` (allowing for signed/unsigned differences). In most cases, `int` is a lot larger than `char`.

`char` is an integer type that is intended to store a character code from the implementation-defined character set, which is required to be compatible with C's abstract basic character set. (ASCII qualifies, so do the source-charset and execution-charset allowed by your compiler, including the one you are actually using.)

For the sizes and ranges of the integer types (`char` included), see your `<limits.h>`. Here is somebody else's [limits.h](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.files/limits.h.htm).

Answer (score -1):

C was designed as a very low-level language, so it is close to the hardware.  Usually, after a bit of experience, you can predict how the compiler will allocate memory, and even pretty accurately what the machine code will look like.

Your intuition is right: it goes back to ASCII.  ASCII is really a simple 1:1 mapping from letters (which make sense in human language) to integer values (that can be worked with by hardware); for every letter there is an unique integer.  For example, the 'letter' CTRL-A is represented by the decimal number '1'.  (For historical reasons, lots of control characters came first - so CTRL-G, which rand the bell on an old teletype terminal, is ASCII code 7.  Upper-case 'A' and the 25 remaining UC letters start at 65, and so on.  See http://www.asciitable.com/ for a full list.)

C lets you 'coerce' variables into other types.  In other words, the compiler cares about (1) the size, in memory, of the var (see 'pointer arithmetic' in K&R), and (2) what operations you can do on it.

If memory serves me right, you can't do arithmetic on a char.  But, if you call it an int, you can.  So, to convert all LC letters to UC, you can do something like:

```
char letter;
....
if(letter-is-upper-case) {
    letter = (int) letter - 32;
}
```

Some (or most) C compilers would complain if you did not reinterpret the var as an int before adding/subtracting.

but, in the end, the type 'char' is just another term for int, really, since ASCII assigns a unique integer for each letter.

Comment: A `char` type is promoted to `int` for arithmetic. And FWIW `'a'` is type `int` anyway.

Comment: Your memory is betraying you. The explicit cast is redundant. See arithmetic promotions.

Comment: Disagree with "you can't do arithmetic on a char.".  `char` is an integer type and can have all sorts of integer math operations performed on objects of that type.

Comment: Yes, simplifying a bit.  The cast, is, in fact, redundant.  More accurately, char* is really the functional equivalent int[ ] (or more maybe even more accurately unsigned int of some such).  I was trying more to convey the idea, which is why I referenced pointer arithmetic.